# Docker swarm node failing 'non-zero exit'

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm working through a getting started example, but I'm having problems when attempting to deploy an image to a swarm.  Specifically, all nodes end up failing with the following error message:

```
"task: non-zero exit (2147516553)"
```

The image works when loaded in a single container - but won't run in a swarm.

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotNetCore.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: [repo]/get-started
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:5000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

It looks like all the nodes start properly (get to a running state).  But then fail with the error message.

Comment: maybe too low memory limit for them?

Comment: Got any application logs?

Comment: Well I've updated the memory limit to 2000M, and restarted... if that's all it was... smh...

Comment: I was about to add that I was able to pull "Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E" from the logs when @v.karbovnichy mentioned the memory might be an issue.

Comment: And that looks like it, they've been running for 5 minutes now (shockingly a new record)... ugh.

Thanks @v.karbovnichy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory limit of 50Mb is definitely too low for your service